# .net core authentication and authorization through web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt

I have tried many things but none seem to be what i'm looking for. I am trying to authenticate my .net core 2.0 mvc app through JWT Tokens and my web api so that none of the database connections are done locally, instead I want them to go to an external source (my web api, to authenticate).

I have searched and nothing is appearing to be the right solution for me, I don't want to use any database connection locally, I just want to use the web api as the source to cross check if the user is a valid one and use that same token to access the web api.

Does anyone know how to use a JWT Token or similar to authenticate a user in both the web app and the web api? To prevent duplication although I wish to have **all** connections to the database handled by the web api and no database connections to be handled by the web app it self

Comment: What is the question here? Please, take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints at how to help the community to help you.

Comment: Please see edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, you want to implement the Identity Provider. Take a look on IdentityServer - it is an opensource Identity provider, implementing OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect out-of-the-box.

- [Home page](http://identityserver.io/)
- [Docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/)
- [Github project](https://github.com/IdentityServer)